# "In your home, what percentage of daily use products are made of plastic or have a high plastic content?"

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

> In your home, what percentage of daily use products are made of plastic or have a high plastic content?

I happened to see this sentence in some survey. However, I think "what percentage of daily use products made of plastic or have plastic content is" would be appropriate sentence. Am I thinking incorrectly or does the sentence of survey have a problem?

Comment: You don't have to thank an answerer in the comments. If you find an answer helpful, please upvote it and/or accept it.

Comment: By the way, as a survey question, this is terrible.  How do you answer it? What even are "daily use products"  How much plastic is "high content". Is a pile of 500 pieces of paper one or 500 products?  Is a phone, cable and charger one, two or three products, and do they have high plastic content.  It is a terrible, unanswerable question.

Comment: I didn't know there is accept function. Sorry, my bad. I just skipped this question since I was quite confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The survey question is better.

It took me a while to work out what your sentence was asking.  I understand that your sentence has the form

> What (...) is.

This isn't a question.  The question form would be  What is (...), ie:

> In your home, what is the percentage of daily use products made of plastic or have a high plastic content?

But this question has problems: the phrase "have a high plastic content" needs to be a participle of some kind, or changed to "with a high...".  You can ask the question like this but it needs some editing to make it correct and clear.

However there is no problem with the original sentence.  The verbs "are made" and "have" agree with the plural "products". It is correct to form a sentence like this.  In a simpler example, it is correct to say

> What percentage of cats are black?

And your sentence has the same basic structure.

The answer could be

> Twenty percent of cats are black.

or in your example:

> Twenty percent of daily use products are made of plastic or have a high plastic content